# How to change button text in a user control using constructor c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

i have made this user control which contain a Button

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace test2
{
public partial class testme : UserControl
{
    public testme()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public testme(string x)
    {
        button1.Text = x;
    }
}
}
```

then i'm trying to change the button in user control using contructor

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace test2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        testme v = new testme("New Text");

}
}
}
```

but when i click at button1 in run time i get this error message 
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overloaded constructor needs to call the constructor with the `InitializeComponent();`, it's called Constructor Chaining, change this line:

```
public testme(string x) : this()
```

Comment: the error was disappeared but the button text wasn't changed

Comment: public partial class testme : UserControl
    {
        public testme()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public testme(string x) : this ()
        {
            button1.Text = x;
        }

Comment: That's because you have instantiated a user control but that control has not been added to the Form.In the button_click add the testme control to the form: `this.Controls.Add(v);`